# Can I calculate regression slope in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

[image]

I have a table like this, NA = NULL value in the table.
I wonder if I could calculate the regression slope for each of the policy.
The formula is as follow[image]
X is the years(2009-2014)
Y is the rate in the table.
For policy 2, I would like to ignore the year with null value and calculate the slope for each of the following year.
IS it possible to do this? Thank you.

[EDIT]
My expected result is as follow,
[image]

Comment: Sure, write a SELECT query to do the calculation and add a WHERE clause that excludes columns with NULL policy percentage.

Comment: Please provide your expected results...